# How to start Apache2 server on embedded linux?

Tags: php, apache2, embedded-linux

I want to use a module running on embedded linux platform to act as a sever for hosting websites. I have downloaded & installed apache2 server on the module but I can't find a command to start/stop the server. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you know what distribution of linux you're using?

Comment: It's Ångström distribution.